# SQL: Want to Update my Table with Attempt No. if a key(combination of key) repeats in a table

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a Table with following values:

```
Enrollment_No   |S_Code  |Reg_Code |Grade|Attempt
----------------------------------------------------
2017001234      |ABC101  |1701     |B    |
2017001234      |ABC102  |1701     |F    |
2017001234      |ABC103  |1701     |C    |
2017001234      |ABC104  |1701     |B    |
2017001234      |ABC105  |1701     |D    |
2017001234      |ABC106  |1702     |A    |
2017001234      |ABC107  |1702     |B    |
2017001234      |ABC108  |1702     |C    |
2017001234      |ABC109  |1702     |D    |
2017001234      |ABC110  |1702     |B    |
2017001234      |ABC102  |1711     |C    |
2017001234      |ABC109  |1711     |C    |
```

[Before Insert Table Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esFqh.jpg)

I want to update(SQL Query) above table with attempt no if same enlrollment_no repeated a S_code in higher registration_code my final table will be like below

```
Enrollment_No   |S_Code  |Reg_Code |Grade|Attempt
----------------------------------------------------
2017001234      |ABC101  |1701     |B    |1
2017001234      |ABC102  |1701     |F    |1
2017001234      |ABC103  |1701     |C    |1
2017001234      |ABC104  |1701     |B    |1
2017001234      |ABC105  |1701     |D    |1
2017001234      |ABC106  |1702     |A    |1
2017001234      |ABC107  |1702     |B    |1
2017001234      |ABC108  |1702     |C    |1
2017001234      |ABC109  |1702     |D    |1
2017001234      |ABC110  |1702     |B    |1
2017001234      |ABC102  |1711     |C    |2
2017001234      |ABC109  |1711     |C    |2
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsVva.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try doing an inline update using SQL Server's `ROW_NUMBER()` to generate the values for the attempt.

```
UPDATE x
SET x.Attempt = x.New_Attempt
FROM
(
    SELECT Attempt,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Enrollment_No, S_Code
                              ORDER BY Reg_Code) AS New_Attempt
    FROM yourTable
) x
```

Comment: Thanks ! you made my day.